# $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t}dt<\infty \implies \lim\limits_{t\to\infty} f(t) = 0?$?

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if a function $f>0$ is such that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t}dt<\infty$ then we have that $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}f(t) = 0$. I was thinking it is not the case. Intuitively if I take $f(t)=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\chi_{(n-{1/n},n+1/n)}$ then $\frac{f(t)}{t}$ would be "more or less" $f(t)=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\chi_{(n-{1/n^2},n+1/n^2)}$ for which the integral if finite.

Comment: Your intuition is pretty good. Instead of that function, you could smoothen it out with bump functions (to guarantee positivity, not just non-negativity) and the logic would follow through the same.

Comment: For $f(t)=\sin t $ the integral is finite ($\frac{\pi}{2}$), yet the limit of $f$ at infinity does not exist.

Comment: But this map is not positive no?

Answer (score 1):

Not only the limit may not be equal to zero... But $f$ can even be unbounded.

An example is the piecewise linear map defined for $n \in \mathbb N$ by

$$f(x)= 
\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{ll} 
    0 & \mbox{if } x=0\\ 
    0 & \mbox{if } x=n-\frac{1}{2n^3}\\ 
    n^2 & \mbox{if } x=n\\ 
    0 & \mbox{if } x=n+\frac{1}{2n^3}\\ 
  \end{array} 
\right.$$

Comment: Have you really written that correctly?

Comment: @md2perpe Where is your doubt?

Comment: the function is constantly zero except at a singular point, and two other points are distinguished for no reason, not clear what you mean

Comment: Does $n$ denote an integer? If so, what if $x$ is neither an integer or of the form $n\pm\frac{1}{2n^3}$ where $n$ is an integer?

Comment: Yes $n$ is an integer. And $f$ is stated to be piecewise linear which provides a definition for any real $x$.

Comment: I guess that what you want is a piecewise linear function with thin triangles placed at integer locations:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 t(n^3(x-n)),
$$
where 
$$
t(x) = \begin{cases}
1+x & \text{if $-1 \leq x \leq 0$} \\
1-x & \text{if $0 \leq x \leq 1$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Exact. See [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/unbounded-continuous-function-with-finite-integral/) for some details.

Comment: It would be clearer if you wrote like on you "blog": "piecewise linear function $f$ /.../ taking following values for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$".